# Extract Data Values from JSON ouput

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am new to JSON and concepts. I want to extract the data from an API which i have mentioned below, basically i want to extract several details from this API about an Stock. The problem here is, after parsing the URL i dont know how to extract the value for each variablle.

I want to extract the data into an GoogleSheet.

the output of the below function shows, like this

[20-12-10 20:45:15:806 CET] [{symbol=JMIA, price=37.0497, volume=1.317713E7}]

The output i wanted is that:

JMIA 
37.0497 
1.317713E7

Code :

```
function CurrentPrice() {
  
           var url = 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote-short/JMIA? 
            apikey=7c2f5bcb573b33050c1aad41a54919';
   
            var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

            // convert json string to json object
            var jsonSignal = JSON.parse(response);    

            Logger.log(jsonSignal);
  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read this "[Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)" article.

The response is wrapped in brackets `[]` meaning it's an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). I assume you're only expecting one response, so you can grab that first element using `jsonSignal[0]`, which will give you an object.

To get an object property, you have to specify the property name using either dot- or bracket-notation. (I'll use dot-notation.)

```js
const jsonSignal = [{symbol:'JMIA', price:37.0497, volume:1.317713E7}]; 
console.log(jsonSignal[0].symbol); // 'JMIA'
```

```
function CurrentPrice() {
  const url = 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote-short/JMIA?apikey=API_KEY';
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  
  // Convert HTTPResponse
  // Use the first element in the response array
  const signal = JSON.parse(response)[0];
  
  console.log(signal.symbol); // 'JMIA'
  console.log(signal.price); // 37.0497
  console.log(signal.volume); // 1.317713E7
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
var json = response.getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(json);
Logger.log(data);
```

I read that there : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external

Regards